# Can I call a base class's virtual function if I'm overriding it?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, overriding

Say I have classes `Foo` and `Bar` set up like this:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    int x;

    virtual void printStuff()
    {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
    int y;

    void printStuff()
    {
        // I would like to call Foo.printStuff() here...
        std::cout << y << std::endl;
    }
};
```

As annotated in the code, I'd like to be able to call the base class's function that I'm overriding. In Java there's the `super.funcname()` syntax. Is this possible in C++?

Comment: possible duplicate of [virtual function call from base class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397404/virtual-function-call-from-base-class)

Comment: For Googlers: note that you may have issues like I did with storing it as a class member variable that's not a pointer. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798966/c-calling-completely-wrong-virtual-method-of-an-object/42429076#42429076 I involved new/delete to fix.

Comment: The Decorator design pattern is based on this :)

Answer (score 545, accepted):

In C++ you have to explicitly name the base class in calling the derived class method. This can be done from any method from the derived class. The override is a special case of the method of the same name. In Java there is no multi inheritance, so you can use super which will uniquely name the base class. The C++ syntax is like this:

```
class Bar : public Foo {
  // ...

  void printStuff() override {  // help the compiler to check
    Foo::printStuff(); // calls base class' function
  }
};
```

Comment: Is there any possible issues with doing this?  Is it bad practice?

Comment: @David: No, it's perfectly normal to do this, though it might depend on your actual class if it is actually useful. Only call the base class method if does something you want to happen ;).

Comment: What is the syntax, if I want to "call" a base class' implementation of an overloaded operator (which in my case is virtual)?

Comment: careful this is a __code smell__ when your clients becomes REQUIRED to do it ! (called `call super requirement`, check it out here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_super)

Comment: @v.oddou: There is nothing wrong with calling the super class when it's useful. That page you linked is just about some specific potential problem involving inheritance. It even says itself that there is nothing wrong with calling the super class in general: *"Note that it is the **requirement** of calling the parent that is the anti-pattern. There are many examples in real code where the method in the subclass may still want the superclass's functionality, usually where it is only augmenting the parent functionality."*

Comment: @sth: yes, this is why I wrote required in all caps. The wiki link was inspired to refect this article by Martin Fowler : http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/CallSuper.html

Comment: It may be obvious to most, but for completeness, remember to never do this in constructors and destructors.

Comment: Regarding @Javy, to execute the baseclass constructor with a parameter the following syntax can be used `constructor(int param) : baseclass(param) { your code ... }`. It is important to remember that objects are constructed bottom up, meaning baseclass constructors are called first. Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/120916/258418)

Comment: To clarify what was said above, I'd say it's a code smell when calling the base class method is part of your public interface. Doing this internally, though, shouldn't be a problem (i.e. among a set of classes that you define together in a single module).

Comment: have not problem using of `::` for calling a `non-static` method?

Comment: @MohammadrezaPanahi in this case, it assumes that the current class is passed as the "this" parameter. (Or rather, that the current environment satisfies the requirements for the super class's functions to be called.

Comment: @TigerCoding why not in constructors? by the time the derived class gets to call anything, construction of the base has already been completed, so calling a base method is safe. (destructors have the opposite order, so for them, the advice works)

Comment: I had a case when I redeclared a method from a base class to only add a __declspec(dllexport) attribute. And I call the base class::methodImpl() in my implementation.

Comment: Please do not gloss over the important comments by NateC-K, v.oddou, and sth.  I've come across confusion about this several times insofar as what best practices are.  To reiterate: there isn't anything necessarily wrong with calling a base class method internally within a set of related classes/etc., but making it a _public_ requirement is usually a sign of bad design.  I.e., try to avoid making users have to worry about running into comments like, "Be sure to call Foo::printStuff() if you override this."

Comment: @TigerCoding: no problem to do base calls on ctor or dtor (23 votes on your coment ?!?!?)

Comment: What if the base class method is private?

Answer (score 140):

Yes,

```
class Bar : public Foo
{
    ...

    void printStuff()
    {
        Foo::printStuff();
    }
};
```

It is the same as `super` in Java, except it allows calling implementations from different bases when you have multiple inheritance.

```
class Foo {
public:
    virtual void foo() {
        ...
    }
};

class Baz {
public:
    virtual void foo() {
        ...
    }
};

class Bar : public Foo, public Baz {
public:
    virtual void foo() {
        // Choose one, or even call both if you need to.
        Foo::foo();
        Baz::foo();
    }
};
```

Comment: This is a better answer than the selected one. Thanks.

Comment: Multiple inheritance? Ooh yikes!

Comment: C++ is crazy , I am almost too after 4 days of dealing with it... If I imagine to write some really complex code as I do in kotlin in C++ I better change my hobby to gradening

Answer (score 87):

Sometimes you need to call the base class' implementation, when you aren't in the derived function...It still works:

```
struct Base
{
    virtual int Foo()
    {
        return -1;
    }
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    virtual int Foo()
    {
        return -2;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Base *x = new Derived;

    ASSERT(-2 == x->Foo());

    //syntax is trippy but it works
    ASSERT(-1 == x->Base::Foo());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that you need both `x` to be of type `Base*` and to use the `Base::Foo` syntax for this to work

Answer (score 29):

Just in case you do this for a lot of functions in your class:

```
class Foo {
public:
  virtual void f1() {
    // ...
  }
  virtual void f2() {
    // ...
  }
  //...
};

class Bar : public Foo {
private:
  typedef Foo super;
public:
  void f1() {
    super::f1();
  }
};
```

This might save a bit of writing if you want to rename Foo.

Comment: Fun way to do it, but will not work with multiple inheritance.

Comment: And what if you have more than 1 base class? Anyway, it is silly and often futile to try to bend C++ to look like some other language. Just remember the base's name and call it by that.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to call a function of base class from its derived class you can simply call inside the overridden function with mentioning base class name(like **Foo::printStuff()**).

code goes here

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Foo
{
public:
    int x;

    virtual void printStuff()
    {
         cout<<"Base Foo printStuff called"<<endl;
    }
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
    int y;

    void printStuff()
    {
        cout<<"derived Bar printStuff called"<<endl;
        Foo::printStuff();/////also called the base class method
    }
};

int main()
{
    Bar *b=new Bar;
    b->printStuff();
}
```

Again you can determine at runtime which function to call using the object of that class(derived or base).But this requires your function at base class must be marked as virtual.

code below

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Foo
{
public:
    int x;

    virtual void printStuff()
    {
         cout<<"Base Foo printStuff called"<<endl;
    }
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
    int y;

    void printStuff()
    {
        cout<<"derived Bar printStuff called"<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{

    Foo *foo=new Foo;
    foo->printStuff();/////this call the base function
    foo=new Bar;
    foo->printStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If there are multiple levels of inheritance, you can specify the direct base class, even if the actual implementation is at a lower level.

```
class Foo
{
public:
  virtual void DoStuff ()
  {
  }
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
};

class Baz : public Bar
{
public:
  void DoStuff ()
  {
    Bar::DoStuff() ;
  }
};
```

In this example, the class **Baz** specifies **Bar::DoStuff()** although the class **Bar** does not contain an implementation of **DoStuff**. That is a detail, which **Baz** does not need to know.

It is clearly a better practice to call **Bar::DoStuff** than **Foo::DoStuff**, in case a later version of **Bar** also overrides this method.

Answer (score 0):

check this...

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Base {
public:
   virtual void gogo(int a) { printf(" Base :: gogo (int) \n"); };    
   virtual void gogo1(int a) { printf(" Base :: gogo1 (int) \n"); };
   void gogo2(int a) { printf(" Base :: gogo2 (int) \n"); };    
   void gogo3(int a) { printf(" Base :: gogo3 (int) \n"); };
};

class Derived : protected Base {
public:
   virtual void gogo(int a) { printf(" Derived :: gogo (int) \n"); };
   void gogo1(int a) { printf(" Derived :: gogo1 (int) \n"); };
   virtual void gogo2(int a) { printf(" Derived :: gogo2 (int) \n"); };
   void gogo3(int a) { printf(" Derived :: gogo3 (int) \n"); };       
};

int main() {
   std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl;
   auto obj = new Derived ;
   obj->gogo(7);
   obj->gogo1(7);
   obj->gogo2(7);
   obj->gogo3(7);
   std::cout << "Base" << std::endl;
   auto base = (Base*)obj;
   base->gogo(7);
   base->gogo1(7);
   base->gogo2(7);
   base->gogo3(7);

   std::string s;
   std::cout << "press any key to exit" << std::endl;
   std::cin >> s;
   return 0;
}
```

output

```
Derived
 Derived :: gogo (int)
 Derived :: gogo1 (int)
 Derived :: gogo2 (int)
 Derived :: gogo3 (int)
Base
 Derived :: gogo (int)
 Derived :: gogo1 (int)
 Base :: gogo2 (int)
 Base :: gogo3 (int)
press any key to exit
```

the best way is using the **base::function** as say @sth

Comment: As explained in [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661936/inheritance-a-is-an-inaccessible-base-of-b), this shouldn't work because of `protected` inheritance. To cast a base class pointer you have to use public inheritance.

Comment: Interesting. After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9661959/6411540) I thought with protected inheritance the fact that Derived is derived from Base would be only visible to the class itself and not visible to the outside too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can call it. C++ syntax for calling parent class function in child class is

```
class child: public parent {
  // ...

  void methodName() {
    parent::methodName(); // calls Parent class' function
  }
};
```

Read more about function [overriding](https://www.codeslehrer.com/function-overriding-c/).