# Question of using static_cast on "this" pointer in a derived object to base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

this is an example taken from *Effective C++ 3ed*, it says that if the `static_cast` is used this way, the base part of the object is copied, and the call is invoked from that part. I wanted to understand what is happening under the hood, will anyone help?

```
class Window {                                // base class
public:
  virtual void onResize() { }                 // base onResize impl
};

class SpecialWindow: public Window {          // derived class
public:
  virtual void onResize() {                   // derived onResize impl;
    static_cast<Window>(*this).onResize();    // cast *this to Window,
                                              // then call its onResize;
                                              // this doesn't work!
                                              // do SpecialWindow-
  }                                           // specific stuff
};
```

Comment: I would remark that since `static_cast<Window>(*this)` creates a copy, this code is most likely **NOT producing the intended result**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This:

```
static_cast<Window>(*this).onResize();
```

is effectively the same as this:

```
{
    Window w = *this;
    w.onResize();
}   // w.~Window() is called to destroy 'w'
```

The first line creates a copy of the `Window` base class subobject of the `SpecialWindow` object pointed to by `this`.  The second line calls `onResize()` on that copy.

This is important:  you never call `Window::onResize()` on the object pointed to by `this`; you call `Window::onResize()` on the copy of `this` that you created.  The object pointed to by `this` is not touched after you make the copy it.

If you want to call `Window::onResize()` on the object pointed to by `this`, [you can do so like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672373/can-i-call-a-base-classs-virtual-function-if-im-overriding-it):

```
Window::onResize();
```

Comment: No, it is the same as `Window w(*this);`.

Answer (score 6):

Why casting? Just do this if you want to call Window's onResize(),

```
Window::onResize(); //self-explanatory!
```

Alright, you can do this same, using static_cast also, but you've to do this way,

```
   static_cast<Window&>(*this).onResize();
    //note '&' here  ^^
```

Comment: That would be true if the OP had used: `static_cast<Window&>` (Notice the & here and the lack of it in the above example).

Comment: What I was trying to say. Was your first version is not equivalent to the OP. This is because the OP version does not use reference and thus creates a copy of (*this) (using the copy constructor) then calls onResize() on the copy (not the current object).

Comment: Why did you use a reference?

Comment: @Lexshard: So that the `static_cast` does not create a copy, in which case it'll call `onResize()` on the copied object which gets destroyed immediately, and the original object remains unchanged. Hope that helps.