# Calling protected base class method via this pointer casted to base class in derived class (C++)

Tags: c++, inheritance, compiler-errors, protected

To begin with, I know about *C++ Standard (ISO/IEC 14882:2003): Section 11.5, Paragraph 1*, and this is not that case (but compliler apparently does not think so).

I try to call protected base class method in derived class method through **this** pointer, static-casted to base class pointer and have in MSVC2008 *error C2248: 'A::f' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'A'*.

I *have* to do this in context of 'curiously recurring template pattern', but I can reproduce this error in simplier code, as follows:

```
class B
{
protected:
    void f(){}
};

class D : public B
{
public:
    void g()
    {
        f(); // ok
        this->f(); // ok
        static_cast<B*>(this)->f(); // C2248 in MSVC2008
        dynamic_cast<B*>(this)->f(); // C2248
        ((B*)this)->f(); // C2248
    }
};
D d; d.g();
```

It seems that compiler think of casted **this** pointer as a pointer to other instance, yeah?

The compiler is wrong in this case, what do you think?

---

Ok, my real code is more like that:

```
template<class T>
class B
{
public:
    void g()
    {
        f(); // error C3861: 'f': identifier not found
        this->f(); // error C3861: 'f': identifier not found

        // static_cast to derived class
        static_cast<T*>(this)->f(); // C2248 in MSVC2008
    }
};

class D : public B<D>
{
protected:
    void f(){}
};
```

I cast **this** to *derived* class, and I *can't* use **this->f();**

---

By the way, I see that this code is unsafe for usage like `class E : public B<D> {...};`: compilable, but static_cast makes wrong cast.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543670/question-of-using-static-cast-on-this-pointer-in-a-derived-object-to-base-clas

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The compiler is correct.  To explicitly access the `B::f` member function, you can write:

```
this->B::f();
```

The relevant language is:

> [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)
>
> #### 11.4 Protected member access [class.protected]
>
> [...] Access to a protected member is granted because the reference occurs in a friend or member of some
>   class C. [...] Access to a protected member [...] involve[s] a (possibly implicit) object expression (5.2.5). In this case,
>   the class of the object expression shall be C or a class derived from C.

Thus protected member access via a cast to the base class `B` violates this grant, and is disallowed.  It is also unnecessary for the reason that you can use `this->B::f()` as above.

---

In the case with your actual CRTP motivation, you are correct that you cannot call `f()` without a `static_cast`, since `D` is not a base class of `B<D>` (the inheritance relationship is in the other direction).  Since `D` is not a base class of `B<D>`, you cannot call its `protected` methods from `B<D>` anyway.  One simple workaround is to `friend` `B<D>` to `D` and use the `static_cast` on the `this` pointer:

```
template<typename T>
class B {
public:
    void g() {
        static_cast<T *>(this)->f();
    }
};

class D : public B<D>
{
    friend class B<D>;
    ...
```

If giving `B` access to the `private` parts of `D` worries you, you can move the `private` parts to another base class and isolate the CRTP mechanism in `D`:

```
template<class T> class B {
public:
    void g() {
        static_cast<T*>(this)->f();
    }
};

class C {
private:
    void h();
protected:
    void f(){ std::cout << "D::f\n"; }
};

class D: protected C, public B<D>
{
    friend class B<D>;
};
```

Here `B<D>` is prevented from calling `C::h` as friendship is neither inherited nor transitive.

Comment: Thank you, but in template version it won't work. `this->T::f()` in `B::g()` causes `error C2039: 'D' : is not a member of 'B<T>'` and `error C2662: 'D::f' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'B<T>' to 'D &'`.

Comment: @Yurash see the extended answer.

Comment: OK, I see, f() should be public.

Comment: It doesn't have to be! You can get CRTP *and* access control; see the last part of my answer.

Comment: @ecatmur: Thank you. I'm reluctant to use `friend`, but in this case it really could be a right solution. Base class is somewhat stable, and I'm not so afraid that it would do something bad to the derived one.

Answer (score 1):

I think the compiler is right.

Suppose the following:

```
void g()
{
    B *b1 = this;
    B *b2 = GetUnrelatedB();
    b1->f(); //Error?
    b2->f(); //Error!
}
```

The `b1` case is equivalent to your `static_cast` but it would be very strange that `b1` will be allowed and `b2` will not.

Citing your paragraph 11.5:

> [...] the access must be through a pointer to, reference to, or object of the derived class itself.

But `static_cast<B*>(this)` is of type `B*`, not `D*`, no matter that the object itself is the same. Actually, the value of the pointer is irrelevant to this issue, only the type of the expression:

```
void g()
{
    B *b2 = GetUnrelatedB();
    static_cast<D*>(b2)->f(); //ok!
}
```

Comment: In template version (see above) I cast to derived class.

Comment: @Yurash: But that makes no sense! You are trying to access to the derived member from the base class. `protected` is supposed to allow the other way around.

Comment: OK, you are right. My first example was not appropriate for the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

But, how would the compiler know that you are inside a class derived from B once you apply `static_cast` on `this`? In my (humble) opinion, if I create a `B` object, I expect not to be allowed to call private or protected `B` methods on the `B` object, since we don't want to violate encapsulation. It would not matter where the `B` object is created, as long as it's outside of the `B` class methods.

Comment: static_cast should somehow know to what it casts. It won't cast to unrelated type.