# Inheritance: 'A' is an inaccessible base of 'B'

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
$ cat inheritance.cpp 
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A { };
class B : private A { };

int main() {
    A* ab = new B;
}
$
$ g++ inheritance.cpp
inheritance.cpp: In function 'int main()':
inheritance.cpp:9: error: 'A' is an inaccessible base of 'B'
$
```

I just do not understand this error.

As I understand, and as [this tutorial](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/115-inheritance-and-access-specifiers/) confirms, `private` inheritance should only change how the members of `class B` are visible to the outside world.

I think the private specifier is doing more than just change visibility of `class B` members here.

- Why do I get this error when inheriting and what does it mean?
- Basically what is wrong with allowing this type of code in C++? Looks totally harmless.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

By making the inheritance private, you're basically saying that even the fact that B inherits from A (at all) is private -- not accessible/visible to the outside world.

Without getting into a long-winded discussion of what would happen if it was allowed, the simple fact is that it's not allowed. If you want to use a pointer to base to refer to an object of derived type, then you're pretty much stuck with using public inheritance.

Private inheritance is *not* necessarily (or even normally) intended to follow the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Public inheritance asserts that a derived object can be substituted for an object of the base class, and proper semantics *will* still result. Private inheritance does **not** assert that though. The usual description of the relationship implied by private inheritance is "is implemented in terms of".

Public inheritance means a derived class maintains all the capabilities of the base class and potentially adds more besides. Private inheritance often means more or less the opposite: that the derived class uses a general base class to implement something with a more restricted interface.

Just for example, let's assume for the moment that the containers in the C++ standard library were implemented using inheritance rather than templates. In the current system, `std::deque` and `std::vector` are containers, and `std::stack` is a container adapter that provides a more restricted interface. Since it is based on templates, you can use `std::stack` as an adapter for either `std::deque` or `std::vector`.

If we wanted to provide essentially the same with inheritance, we would probably use private inheritance, so `std::stack` would be something like:

```
class stack : private vector {
    // ...
};
```

In this case, we definitely do *not* want the user to be able to manipulate our `stack` as if it were a `vector`. Doing so could (and likely would) violate the expectations of a stack (e.g., the user could insert/remove items in the middle, rather than a purely stack-like fashion as intended). We're basically using `vector` as a convenient way to implement our stack, but if (for example) we changed the implementation for `stack` stand alone (with no dependence on a base class) or re-implement it in terms of `std::deque`, we do *not* want that to affect any client code -- to the client code, this is supposed to be just a stack, not some specialized variety of vector (or deque).

Comment: this also applies to `protected`

Comment: But we can create getters that returns `this` as pointer to base class.

Comment: @KeshavSahu: Oh, of course. As the old saying goes, C++ tries to protect against Murphy, not Machiavelli. In other words, it tries to protect you from accidents, but if you write the code to bypass its protection, it won't try to stop you.

Answer (score 15):

> private inheritance should only change how the members of class B are visible to the outside world

It does.  And if

```
A* p = new B;
```

were allowed, then the inherited members of any `B` could be accessed from the outside world, just by making a `A*`.  Since they're privately inherited, that access is illegal, and so is the upcast.

Answer (score 10):

`clang++` gives a slightly more understandable error message:

```
example.cpp:9:13: error: cannot cast 'B' to its private base class 'A'
    A* ab = new B;
            ^
example.cpp:6:11: note: declared private here
class B : private A { };
          ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I'm not a C++ expert, but it looks like it's just simply not allowed.  I'll go poke around the spec and see what I come up with.

Edit:  here's the relevant reference from the spec - Section **4.10 Pointer conversions**, paragraph 3:

> A prvalue of type "pointer to *cv* `D`", where `D` is a class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type "pointer to cv `B`", where B is a base class of `D`. If `B` is an inaccessible or ambiguous base class of `D`, a program that necessitates this conversion is ill-formed.

Answer (score 6):

It's pretty simple: the fact that `A` is inherited privately means that the fact that `B` extends `A` is a secret, and only `B` "knows" it. That is the very definition of private inheritance.

Comment: But I get the very same error if I replace `private` with `protected`.

Comment: Indeed. "Protected" means that the knowledge is limited to `B` and subclasses (and friends) of `B`. "`A* ab = new B;`" would be legal in a hypothetical class `C` that was a subclass of `B`.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill: No, it wouldn't.  `protected` gives `class C : B` additional access to base subobjects of class `C`, not to instances of `B` which aren't `C`.

Comment: @BenVoigt I’m not a language lawyer so perhaps the spec forbids it, but I just tried an example and clang 14.0 was fine with it.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill: It is, and it is also contradictory.  `b->x` is unambiguous and inaccessible but `b->A::x` is allowed.  From type-safety theory that's bad.

https://rextester.com/ZIQ63865

Answer (score 3):

Private inheritance means that outside the derived class, the inheritance information is hidden.  That means you can't cast the derived class to the base class: the relationship isn't known to the caller.

Comment: Thanks, but it somehow doesn't make sense. `private`s only business should be to control how the members behave. What would be the harm if the inheritance information is not hidden?

Comment: Private inheritance is a form of aggregation/composition. It's a way to *have* the properties of a base class, without *being* an object of the base class. If that isn't what you want, private inheritance isn't for you. That's just how it works.

Answer (score 3):

This is working

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{
    public:
        virtual void update() = 0;
};

class B: public A{
    public:
    virtual void update(){std::cout<<"hello";};
};

int main()
{
    A *a = new B();

    a->update();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Base pointer can access only those functions of Derived which are inherited by Base, and can not access Derived exclusive functions.

```
class B { public: void fb() { ... } };
class D : public B { public: void fd() { ... } };

B* b = new D;
b->fb(); // ok
b->fd(); // not allowed
```

With private inheritance, `fb` will be a private member in Derived. So, there will be nothing that Base pointer can access from Derived object. That is why it is not allowed in the first place.