# Does a function that takes a pointer to base class also accept a child class that derived privately from the base class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, private

This came up in my c++ class, let say we have a base class with some public functions.

```
class basevector {
public:
virtual int indexTo(int arg);
virtual int getSize() const;
virtual int push(int);
virtual int pop(int);
}
```

then we have a class that derives privately

```
class myvector : private basevector{
public :  
virtual int push(int);
virtual int pop(int);
virtual int getSize() const;
}
```

Notice that the myvector class restricts access to the indexTo function and forces the user to use the push and pop.

Now if I have a function that takes a pointer to basevector

```
void do_something(basevector * arg) {
    for(int i = 0; i < arg->getSize(); i++) {
        int k = arg->indexTo(i);
        do_something_else(k);
    }
}
```

I then try to do the following

```
basevector * ptr = nullptr;
ptr = new myvector;

do_something(ptr);
```

What happens? `myvector` is a `basevector` but a function that tries to use the public `indexTo` function in `basevector` will fail on a `myvector`.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: No I didn't get to try it, it just came up in lecture. How would the do_something function have access to indexAt member function if it is a private function inside of myvector?

Comment: All it can see is the base class, and unless your base class has virtual methods all it will call is methods in the base class. It doesn't care that the base class was privately extended by the derived class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to virtual functions! Whenever you mark a function in a class as `virtual` you're telling the compiler, "Hey, I might override this function later. If I do, then make sure to use the new overridden version!". It has nothing to do with restricting access to functions within a class. That's what the `public` keyword does.

In your specific example, you can access all four functions from both `basevector` and `myvector`. However, what those functions represent is dependent on the type of the value that you're using (not the type of the pointer!) When you create a `new myvector`, you're also creating a table that points to the functions that it should use:

```
push    --> myvector::push
pop     --> myvector::pop
getSize --> myvector::getSize
indexTo --> basevector::indexTo
```

That last one happens automatically because you're inheriting from `basevector` when you declare `myvector`. In your definition of `myvector` though, you've overridden the other three.

OK. So what?

Well, when you define a new function that takes a generic `basevector`, like `do_something`, the compiler knows that `basevector` has virtual functions. Whenever it invokes one of these functions, it has to go look in the table that was generated when the `basevector` was created. In your example, that table is the table from a `myvector`. Hence, `do_something` will call `basevector`'s `indexTo` regardless of whether or not you pass in a `basevector` or `myvector`.

You can actually **force** `myvector` to implement its own version of `indexTo`:

```
class basevector {
  public:
    virtual int indexTo(int arg) = 0;
    /* ... */
};
```

Now if you try and create a `new myvector`, the compiler will complain saying that it can't find something to point to for its `indexTo` entry in it's virtual function table (commonly called a "V-table").

However, when it comes to private inheritance, you should treat it as the following:

```
class A : private B { ...
```

this means "Everything that an A has access to in B will be private to people outside of A". So later, you can do things like:

```
myvector *p1 = new myvector;
basevector *p2;
// p2 = p1;    // <-- Compiler will complain here because we don't know that
               // basevector is a base class of myvector!
p2 = reinterpret_cast<basevector *>(p1);
p2->pop();  // Super hacky but identical to calling p1->pop();
```

However, as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661936/inheritance-a-is-an-inaccessible-base-of-b#answer-9661959), using private inheritance hides that `basevector` is the base class of `myvector` too! Since we know it is, we can cast the pointer
to a `basevector` and elicit the same behavior because we know how virtual functions work.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, a function shouldn't care about the child class or how it inherits from the base, so assuming you had such a pointer, yes the function would operate on it normally. However in practice, the answer is no, because a base class pointer to an instance of a child class that inherited privately [can't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661936/inheritance-a-is-an-inaccessible-base-of-b#answer-9661959).

In essence, private inheritance is like secret inheritance—the very fact that the child class inherits from the base class is not externally visible. So, the compiler will not even let you do what you wrote:

```
basevector * ptr = nullptr;
ptr = new myvector;
```

Because of the rules of private inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your code will not even compile when using private inheritance.  Because `basevector` is privately inherited, you cannot assign a `myvector*` pointer to a `basevector*` pointer at all, the compiler complains:

```
Cannot convert 'myvector *' to 'basevector *'
```

As soon as you change `private` to `public` inheritance, it works fine.

But, let's say you *could* assign a `myvector*` to a `basevector*`.  `indexAt()` is declared as `public` in `basevector`, and `do_something()` is accessing `basevector` directly, so it has access to `indexAt()`.