# No matching conversion for functional-style cast from 'B *' to 'std::shared_ptr<A>'

Tags: class, c++11, shared-ptr, declaration, access-control

I have  a simple appliction that tries to initialize a shared ptr.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

class A {
public:
    A(){
        std::cout << "default ctor for A" << std::endl;
    }
    ~A(){
        std::cout << "default dtor for A" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B : A{
    B(){
        std::cout << "default ctor for B" << std::endl;
    }
    ~B(){
        std::cout << "default dtor for B" << std::endl;
    }
};



int main()
{

    auto ap = std::shared_ptr<A>(new B());
    
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the error

```
No matching conversion for functional-style cast from 'B *' to 'std::shared_ptr<A>'
```

in this line
auto ap = std::shared_ptr(new B());

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661936/inheritance-a-is-an-inaccessible-base-of-b, in short: `class B : public A{ public:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class B should be declared like

```
class B : public A{
public:
    B(){
        std::cout << "default ctor for B" << std::endl;
    }
    ~B(){
        std::cout << "default dtor for B" << std::endl;
    }
};
```