# how can I use an inherited method and the same base class method?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, virtual

let's say I have a class animal and a class dog that inherits animal.  Let's say I want to call a method called 'eat()' that is specific to dog but there is some shared eat code between all animals, so I know I can make 'eat()' virtual but then it won't use the base class code, should I just call my base class 'eatAll()', for example, and then every eat method from a specific animal will have to call that?  Just looking for the best design I guess.  This is in c++

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672373/can-i-call-a-base-classs-virtual-function-if-im-overriding-it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is classic [**template method pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). Basically:

```
class Animal
{
    void Eat() 
    {
       //stuff specific to all animals

       SpecificEat();
    }
    virtual void SpecificEat() = 0;
};

class Dog : Animal
{
    virtual void SpecificEat()
    {
        //stuff specific to dog
    }
};
```

Using this approach, you don't have to explicitly call the base class method in derived classes' overrides. It's called automatically by the non-`virtual` `Eat()` and the specific functionality is implemented by `virtual SpecificEat()`.

Comment: what if eat is not void? what if it's a bool for example, how do you work that in?

Comment: @Pittfall the `=0` is the only thing that's valid there, and indicates a pure virtual function. `=true` doesn't make sense. If that confuses you, read up on pure virtual functions and remove the `=0`.

Comment: got it read about pure virtual functions and it makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest that your base class interface have hooks to call into specific functionality of derived types. This is called the [template method pattern.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)  Here's an example:

```
class Animal
{
public:
   void eat()
   {
      std::cout << "Mmmm... It's ";
      do_eat();
   }

private:
   virtual void do_eat() = 0;
};

class Dog
   : public Animal
{
   virtual void do_eat()
   {
      std::cout << "Dog Food!\n";
   }
};

class Human
   : public Animal
{
   virtual void do_eat()
   {
      std::cout << "Pizza!\n";
   }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Just call the base class' method.

```
class Dog : public Animal
{
public :
  void Eat()
  {
    // .. MAGIC
    Animal::Eat();
  }
};
```

Note that if your Animal class's `Eat` method is pure virtual (which I doubt), this will not link.

Comment: I have already mentioned in my question that I can call the base method from dog and the question was more directed for someone who can back up a good design.  "Magic" was not exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @Pittfall: "MAGIC" was just a placeholder for whatever you do in the derived class.