# Is there a way to call a base function outside of the class in C++?

Tags: c++, oop

This question is similar, but is about calling the function from inside the class: [Can I call a base class's virtual function if I'm overriding it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672373/can-i-call-a-base-classs-virtual-function-if-im-overriding-it)

In that case, you'd specify `Base::function()` instead of `function()`, which will call the overridden definition.

But is there a way to do this outside of the class? My class doesn't define a copy constructor, so I couldn't figure out how to cast as the base class:

```
Base( derived_object ).function()
```

Is the appropriate thing to do here to cast `& derived_object` as `Base*` and then call `->function()`?

Thanks for your insight.

Comment: `static_cast` might work, although I'm not sure - the point of virtual functions is that they are resolved at runtime, independently of the object's compile time type.. `dynamic_cast` will certainly not work.

Comment: Why would you want to? If function is part of the derived class and also in base-class, then you are probably doing something wrong when you call the base-class. The better way to solve that is to make a separate function in the base-class that is meant to be called by the derived class, and let the base-class call that functoion itself.

Comment: Please see comment to @Omnifarious below.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try `derived_object.Base::function();`

Explanation: `Class::function` is the 'full name' of a member function. If you don't specify the `Class::` prefix for the function call, it would look up the 'default' one (in your case: the derived one).

Comment: @Oliver: Yes it is standard.

Comment: @Oliver   class::function() is the 'full name' of a member function. If you don't specify the class for the function you called, it would be the 'default'(derived one in your case) one.

Answer (score 13):

I believe the syntax:

```
derived_ptr->Base::function();
```

works just fine. Though I really question why you would want to do this in a function that's not part of your class. Especially if `function` happens to be a virtual function.

The reason why it's a questionable idea is that you're making whatever it is that uses that notation depend on the inheritance hierarchy of your class. Also, functions are usually overridden for a reason. And you're getting around that by using this syntax.

Comment: Thanks-- I have an Base object that makes a report, and the Derived object that generates a report (with extra information over the base report). So I create the base report via Base::generate_report and then copy in the extra information. This is done outside the class using a visitor pattern (better separation of concerns)-- BaseReport is constructed with a Base and DerivedReport is constructed with a Derived. Phew!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use pointers to member functions of a class. Those give you the ability to map different base class functions to the pointer as needed, and the ability to use it as a variable or function parameter.

The syntax for a pointer to a member function looks like

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual bool Function();
    virtual bool OtherFunction();
};

typedef bool (Base::*)() BaseFunc;
```

The list of caveats for using these things is a mile long- there is plenty online on how to use them (most of the answers are "don't"). However, they do give you a way of clearly binding to and calling a base class member function.