# Virtual function in c++

Tags: c++, virtual

I have declared a virtual method in super class. I want to call that method using the super class pointer which is pointing to the sub class object. For example:

```
class A            { virtual void foo(); }
class B : public A { virtual void foo(); }

A *b = new B();
```

Comment: maybe this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672373/can-i-call-a-base-classs-virtual-function-if-im-overriding-it or google is your friend: http://google.com/search?hl=en&num=50&safe=off&q=c%2B%2B+call+virtual+super+function

Comment: @Saksham yes he does, to call the base class method.

Answer (score 1):

The approach is good, but `A::foo()` is `private` - to call it, it would need to be `public`.

You're also missing the implementations and the trailing `;` after the class definition.

Comment: class A     
 {
public virtual void foo(); 
}I should mention as public to acces it rite???