# C++ method pointer to overriden method

Tags: c++, multithreading, polymorphism, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I recently finished a bit of a program that I was hoping would work the way I expected it to, and as it turns out, it did! Here is the situation:

I have a `Handler` class which is the base class:

```
class Handler
{
public:
    Handler();
    virtual ~Handler();
    virtual void handle(SOCKET socket);

protected:
    virtual void doWork(SOCKET socket);


private:
    std::thread * handlerThread;
    static void processData(SOCKET socket);
};
```

I have a `PrintHandler` which is a subclass of `Handler`:

```
class PrintHandler : public Handler
{
public:
    PrintHandler();
    ~PrintHandler();

protected:
    virtual void doWork(SOCKET socket);
};
```

Here are the definitions of doWork in the base class `Handler` and the subclass `PrintHandler`:

```
void Handler::doWork(SOCKET socket)
{
    std::cerr << "If you see this, you didn't override the doWork function" << std::endl;
}

void PrintHandler::doWork(SOCKET socket)
{
    std::cerr << "This is in the base class" << std::endl;
}
```

When I create a pointer to a `PrintHandler` and cast it to a pointer to a `Handler` and call the `handle` method on that object via method pointer:

```
void Handler::handle(SOCKET socket)
{
    handlerThread = new std::thread(&Handler::doWork, this, socket);
}
```

the `doWork`executes as the subclass method that overrode the base class method. **When I override a method in the manner that I did, does it replace the base class method in memory? Is there anyway to call the original base class doWork method? Does calling it with a method pointer change which method gets called?**

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672373/can-i-call-a-base-classs-virtual-function-if-im-overriding-it) thread it gives you a means to do it from the sub class. **How would I call the original base class method from the base class and what does the actual structure of the object look like in memory?**

I understand this is probably a lot to answer, so if you could maybe provide your knowledge on the questions in the first paragraph and suggest some reading for the questions in the second, I think that would be most appropriate.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> When I override a method in the manner that I did, does it replace the base class method in memory?

No, both functions still exist. Overriding affects which version is chosen when called on a particular object; the base version is still needed for objects of that type, or other derived classes that don't override it.

> Is there anyway to call the original base class doWork method?

Yes, you can call it non-virtually:

```
Handler::doWork();
```

> Does calling it with a method pointer change which method gets called?

No, virtual dispatch chooses the same override whether you call the function directly, or via a pointer-to-member-funcion. It only depends on the dynamic type of the object it's called on.

> what does the actual structure of the object look like in memory?

That's up to the implementation. Typically, the object contains a pointer (known as a *vptr* or *virtual pointer*) to some class-specific metadata, which contains a table of pointers to the virtual functions (known as a *vtable*). When you (virtually) call a virtual function, it looks in that table to find which function to call. A pointer to a virtual function will specify which table entry to use, rather than which function to call, so that virtual dispatch still works on any type that overrides that function.

Comment: You say calling `Handler::doWork();` is non virtual, but in my code `handlerThread = new std::thread(&Handler::doWork, this, socket);` calls the derived `doWork()`. Aren't those two calls the same thing, but on just uses a pointer to a member function instead?

Comment: @MattVaughan: No, you get virtual dispatch when you use a pointer-to-member-function, as my answer describes.

Comment: Alright thank you. I think the Handle:: prefix is what's got me confused, but it sounds like even if you use that with a pointer-to-member-function it will use the most derived if it is a virtual function despite the prefix.

Answer (score 1):

when you do

```
std::thread(&Handler::doWork, this, socket);
```

You ask to call `this->doWork(socket)` virtually.

You may create an other method which call not virtually your virtual method. as:

```
void Handler::callHandlerDoWork(SOCKET socket)
{
    Handler::doWork(socket); /* no virtual call */
}

void Handler::handle(SOCKET socket)
{
    handlerThread = new std::thread(&Handler::callHandlerDoWork, this, socket);
}
```

Note: Do you really need that `Handler::handle` is `virtual` ?

Comment: The way it calls the sub class instead of the base class is what I wanted. But I couldn't think of a way to just call the base class. I have it as virtual so that other classes can define thread behavior.