# How to call the overriden function of parent class in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

The expected output:

```
Child = 2
Parent = 1
```

My code:

```
class Parent{
    int a;
    public:
        void display(){
            a = 1;
            cout << "Parent = " << a << endl;
        }
};

class Child:public Parent{
    int b;
    public:
        void display(){
            b = 2;
            cout << "Child = " << b << endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    Parent *p = new Child();
    Child c;

    //write your code here
    /* My solution :
      c.display();
      Parent* a = &c;
      a->display();
    */


}
```

I made use of static binding to successfully call the display() member function of the parent class

However, I wonder if there is any better solution for this question.

What is the purpose of having this line `Parent *p = new Child();`?  Is it a pointer pointing to a constructor?

What is the difference between that line and `Parent *p = new Child;`?

Comment: This would be the duplicate if you had correctly used virtual methods to implement overriding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672373/can-i-call-a-base-classs-virtual-function-if-im-overriding-it.

Comment: What do you mean "what is the purpose of having this line"?  If you don't know why it is there, why do you have it?  Is this a homework question?

Comment: Yup this is a homework question.The code structure given cannot be modified.I'm only allowed to add my code in that specified area.I'm able to produce the desired output but this line  "Parent *p = new Child();" is not useful at all for my solution.So I wonder what is the purpose of having this line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to call the overriden function of parent class in C++?

You haven't actually overridden any function in your example. Only virtual member functions can be overridden, and `display` is non-virtual.

> I made use of static binding to successfully call the display() member function of the parent class

Your solution works because there is no overriding or virtual functions involved. Another way to call the hidden member function is to use the scope resolution operator:

```
c.Parent::display();
```

This would use static binding even if the function was virtual.

---

> What is the purpose of having this line `Parent *p = new Child();`?

It doesn't seem to have any purpose in your program. In general, `new` is used to allocate objects dynamically from the free store.

Note that the memory will be leaked unless you explicitly deallocate it with `delete`. Also not that `delete p` would have undefined behaviour, because it points to a base whose destructor is non-virtual.

> Is it a pointer pointing to a constructor?

No. `p` points to the dynamic object that was created in the free store.

> What is the difference between that line and `Parent *p = new Child;`?

Without parentheses, you use default initialisation syntax. With empty parentheses you use value initialisation.

In the case of trivially constrtuctible classes (such as `Parent`), default initialisation will default initialise the members. In case of integer members, this leaves the members uninitialised. Value initialisation will instead value initialise the members, which for integers means initialisation to zero.

In the case of non-trivially constructible classes (such as `Child`), both default and value initialisation invoke the default constructor.

Comment: If the parenthesis doesn't hold any value, means it's the same as the one without parenthesis,is it?

Comment: Someone told me this is an upcasting "Parent *p = new Child" ...

Comment: @XinYi Yes. There is an implicit conversion from derived pointer to base pointer. Such conversion is called an upcast. Similar conversion is done on the line `Parent* a = &c`.

Comment: In that case, I can also use p->display(); to get the desired output.Thank you very much!!!! =]

Answer (score 4):

There are several points to make here:

1. `Child` is not overriding anything, it is only hiding the base class method. Overriding would require `virtual` member functions, and you can verify that a method actually overrides a base class function by adding the `override` keyword. Neither class is polymorphic, because there are no virtual methods anywhere.
2. Since your classes are not polymorphic, you will only ever have static binding, no dynamic binding. (You correctly identified this happening).
3. To call a base class function that was overridden or hidden in a derived class, you prefix the call with the base class name and `::`, like so:

   ```
   class Child : public Parent{
     int b;
     public:
       void display(){
         Parent::display();
       }
   };

   // or

   int main()
   {
     Child c;
     c.Parent::display();
   }
   ```
4. There is no difference between `Parent *p = new Child();` and `Parent *p = new Child;` in your code, both call the default constructor to initialize a new child object. For types like `int` there is a difference, `new int;` creates an uninitialized `int` object, `new int();` (or `new int{};`) initializes it to zero instead.