# Visual Studio 2017 how to jump to C++ base method

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Suppose a C++ method overrides a base class's method, then how to jump to the definition/declaration of the base method from the source of method? (e.g. pop up a window to show a list of base methods that it overrides)

Comment: use ParentClass::methodOverrided(params...);   see here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672373/can-i-call-a-base-classs-virtual-function-if-im-overriding-it

Comment: @ Eric The question is about how to use VS2017

Comment: This seems impossible even in VS2019 which is very frustrating. VS knows the base method, it even warns you if it doesn't exist, but VS won't tell you where it is. Hope this feautre will be implemented soon.