# How do you call a virtual function inside the base class?(C++)

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

What I have is the following:

```
class A{

public:
   virtual void OnStart() = 0;
   void GameLoop(){
      OnStart();
      //Do other stuff
   }

};

class B : public A{
   void OnStart() override{
      //Do Something
   }
};
```

Now I have the problem that it either doesn't call OnStart at all or it gives me an error. I have also tried `this->OnStart()` but none of the things I have tried worked.

Comment: Please show the code that has the error or works not how you expect. The code you posted does not have that issue, but others. For starters `virtual void OnStart = 0;` is not valid syntax

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I call a base class's virtual function if I'm overriding it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672373/can-i-call-a-base-classs-virtual-function-if-im-overriding-it)

Comment: I've tried your code [here](https://onecompiler.com/cpp/3x379s5eq). and it works with the added `()` brackets as suggested by the others. Just make sure you create an instance of class B and not of A.

Answer (score 2):

You should declare the virtual `OnStart` as a function.

```
class A{

public:
   virtual void OnStart() = 0; // add () to declare it as a function (with no arguments)
   void GameLoop(){
      OnStart();
      //Do other stuff
   }

};

class B : public A{
   void OnStart() override{
      //Do Something
   }
};
```

Comment: I just typed it wrong there, but I already figured it out. But still thanks for your answer.