# Modifying part of interface in C++

Tags: c++

Say I have an interface I:

```
class I
{
public:
    virtual int f() = 0;
};
```

and class B implementing I:

```
class B: public I
{
public:
    int f() override { return 1; }
    ...
}
```

can I define a (template) class C so that:

- class C implements I.
- class C implements everything else B has without writing a wrapper for every B function.
- class C overrides f().
- underlying B instance uses unmodified B::f().

?

Comment: sounds like `class C : public B { int f() override; };`

Comment: This will completely override f() for the instance of B as well.

Comment: I don't follow your last bullet point. Under what circumstances would you expect to be able to invoke the "underlying B instance" and have it use `B::f`?

Comment: Say I have B::g() that calls f(). I want it to use B::f(), not C::f().

Comment: Try explicitly calling B::f() or this->B::f() in B

Comment: For me question suffers from [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please [edit] question and improve it.

Comment: Ok, I need to transparently modify a stream without knowing full features of it. Does it help?

Comment: the solution in my comment should work, cf. also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672373/can-i-call-a-base-classs-virtual-function-if-im-overriding-it