Switch case: Return from impossible default case
What to do if I use a switch case in a function, and the default case should not happen, yet I must return something?
I tried to program some cellular automaton, where there are two possible cell states: ALIVE and DEAD. The code looks something like this?
State find_next_cell_state(const Cell& cell, State current_state)
{
    switch (current_state)
    {
    case ALIVE:
    // Blah Blah...

    case DEAD:
    // Blah Blah...

    default: // Should never reach here unless I make a mistake.
    // What to add here? Throw an Exception? Return garbage?
    }
}

The problem with throwing an exception is that an assert seems much more fitting for checking this sort of stuff, yet putting an assert at the end doesn't seems correct. Returning some garbage also doesn't seem like a smart thing to do.
Since I find a switch case to be much more idiomatic than if-else in this case, is there an elegant way to overcome this?

"putting an assert at the end doesn't seems correct" Why not? Also if you only have two states, it sounds like a job for bool, not a enum, then you won't have this problem. Also I recommend not adding a default: branch to enable the warning for unhandled enum values (on GCC & Clang), and handle invalid values below the switch instead.

assert is a macro that expands to something that does nothing in a typical release build. And it terminates the process in a way that makes it looks like a crash, which is never a good idea. Throw an exception that can be handled by the code at an appropriate level.

@HolyBlackCat Because it makes much more sense to me to assert at the beginning. But if I assert at the beginning, I still need to return something at the end of the function.

throw "some error message" works. The compiler recognises that throw does not return

Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649423/should-switch-statements-always-contain-a-default-clause

@Someprogrammerdude "And it terminates the process in a way that makes it looks like a crash, which is never a good idea." - I strongly disagree: failing-fast at runtime is usually a good idea, though Ill concede that assert() doesn't have the best dev-ex overall.

Alternatively if you are using C++11 define a function [[noreturn]] void fatal_error(const char* msg) ... Then use fatal_error("some error message"); in your default. Again the noreturn attribute tells the compiler that this function is not going to return, so should suppress any error messages.

"still need to return something at the end of the function" Why do you think you do? You can just not return anything and get UB. This has the same effect in release builds (UB), and same effect in debug builds (assert triggers before reaching end of function).

@john I was always told that exceptions should handle problems with the workflow, not programming mistakes (that is what assert is for). It might work, but it seems clumsy.

@Dai When a user see a "crash" it will upset them, and complain. Loudly and often. Fail early is good, but fail in a nice and user-friendly way instead. Which assert doesn't do (if it runs, remember that it doesn't do anything in release builds).

@PlsHelp Then write a [[noreturn]] function for your programming mistakes.

@PlsHelp "exceptions should handle problems with the workflow, not programming mistakes" - I think you're misremembering what was actually told to you... (assuming "exceptions for programming mistakes" means precondition/postcondition or class-invariant assertions).

@HolyBlackCat I need to return because otherwise a warning will be generated, so it will not compile.

@Dai That's what I got from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409794/exception-vs-assert.

@PlsHelp If State is a scoped enumeration, you should not need a default case. Unless you expect your fellow programmers to do some really bad things (like explicitly converting some random number to a State).

@PlsHelp What kind of C++ are you writing? I ask, because writing C++ for Win32 specifically means you should be using Win32 SEH (with the __try/__except/__finally language-extensions) - but if you're writing portable C++ then different guidelines should be followed...

This question is similar to: How to code for exhaustiveness with C++ enum+switch statement. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

"otherwise a warning will be generated" Isn't it generated either way (with assert at the beginning or at the end of the function?). There are a few things you could place at the end of function to get rid of this: std::unreachable(), a dummy return {}; (if your return type is default-constructible), std::terminate, etc.

@Dai It is different: In the the linked question, it was asked how to get the compiler to warn about unhandled cases. I ask about best practice for handling a default case which should not happen.

@PlsHelp Yes, that's what "exhaustiveness" means - and both you (and the linked OP) are asking how to force the compiler to recognize an exhaustive switch and so (in your casse) so it won't warn you about any case (including default) missing a return.

@PlsHelp The first thing I'd do would be to make State an enum class to make it harder to make mistakes.

I would use assert(false) (to help in debug mode during development) and std::unreachable.

I like the idea of std::unreachable. Shame it's C++23, so it is unlikely to be used anytime soon in a professional setting.

@PlsHelp: You can easily re-implement it, link provides possible implementation (even an empty one is correct.

My shop is already using C++20, and preparing to welcome C++23 as support comes in. And we have heaps of legacy code. I wouldn't say it's too far of.

@PlsHelp see the possible implementation in the link. If cppref is correct, all you need is that.

One way to address this sort of situation is to assert not that some code isn’t reached but that the last case is the expected one:
switch (current_state)
{
case ALIVE:
// Blah Blah...

default:
assert(current_state == DEAD);
// Blah Blah...
}

Then there simply is no exceptional code path that you need to call out to the compiler.
Obviously this looks more than a little strange with just two cases, and it does potentially lead to forgetting to add a new enumerator in the future (but at least there’s an assertion for that case if you hit it).
