# Java Assert statement usage, exam certification 1Z0-851

Tags: java

I am studing for 1Z0-851 Oracla Java SE 1.6 Certification and I saw this question:

[image: Question from test]

I marked the first alternative as the correct one and failed! "All of the assert statements are used appropriately" and the answer says that the first one `assert(x > 0);` is incorrect.. the question is why?

Comment: The term "used appropriately" is very subjective, hence the confusion. They should clarify that question.

Comment: Also look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957645/when-to-use-assertion-vs-exception)

Comment: It would really help if they used a code sample that made even a small amount of sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct answer is this

**Appropriate and inappropriate use of assertions**

*You can place an assertion at any location that you don't expect to be reached normally.
Assertions can be used to validate the parameters passed to a private method. However,
assertions should not be used to validate parameters passed to public methods because a
public method must check its arguments regardless of whether assertions are enabled or
not. However, you can test postconditions with assertions in both public and non-public
methods. Also, assertions should not change the state of a program in any manner.*

Src: http://www.freejavaguide.com/java-scjp-part1.pdf

Comment: +1 Nice, didnt know that. Although personally I only ever use assertions in unit tests..!

Answer (score 3):

Line 12 is redundant.

if you remove it, the assertion on line 15 will cover the case where `x <= 0`

To be honest its a strangely worded question but that is all I can see. I am not sure what is meant by appropriately

Answer (score 1):

If you read just the first assert statement -- which should be interpreted as a "precondition" because of its position --, it implies that the function should work properly with any positive int value, which is not true. Therefore, that assertion is misleading.

Comment: The function doesn't work for any values of x.  Either it's a negative number and fails the first, or it `assert false`s.

Answer (score 0):

Starting by `go2`, it is easy to understand the assert.
The method does nothing, it just asserts your expectation, that `x < 0`.

The `go` method, on the other hand, has a `switch`.
It is good practice to `assert false` on the `default` clause, if you **absolutely** do not expect your program to fall under this clause, *ie*, under normal circumstances, one of the `case`s has to be correct.

The only case on the `switch` expects `x` to be **exactly** `2`.
<del>So, to sum up, you don't expect `x` to be greater than `0`, as the first assertion says, you expect `x` to be `2` and nothing else. Thus, the assertion is not used appropriately.</del>

However, as [Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1435657/jeff) noted, the `case` has no `break`, which means the `default` will always be executed, leading, in every scenario, to `assert false`.

**Conclusion:** The `go` method should always result in an error, making `assert false` properly used, while `assert x > 0` isn't correct at all.

Comment: Except that the `case 2` doesn't have a corresponding `break`, which means it will always fall through to the `assert false` as well.

Comment: Nicely spotted. I automatically assumed the `break`.

Comment: Me too when I first read it.  That's why I had to delete my own answer.  Haha

Comment: Good spot, I missed it too. My answer just about stands anyway, however the question does seem nonsensical

Comment: @Jeff Edited, according to your comment.