# Assertion VS Runtime exception

Tags: java, runtime-error

I am writing API, so my API will be used from external modules. And here is a one of methods where I can't figure out what to use assertion or `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`

```
/**
 * Adds translation of information to underlying store for particular language
 * @param languageId The identifier of the language 
 * @param translation The translation provided for the specific language
 * @throws AssertionError if the provided language id is {@code null} or empty
 *         or provided translation is {@code null} or empty
 */
public final void addTranslation(String languageId, String translation){
    assert !(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(languageId));
    assert !(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(translation));

    translations.put(languageId, translation);
}
```

If I use runtime exception, I think that it may harm the execution of the application which is using this API. If I use assertion then it will harm my API, if the assertion flag is disabled.

Also tried to read similar post [When to use an assertion and when to use an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957645/when-to-use-assertion-vs-exception). But it is bit confusing to detect which case is mine.

**Is there a strictly defined way, where to use assertions and where to use runtime exceptions?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception Vs Assertion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276308/exception-vs-assertion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assertions are usually a development technique that can be switched off in production.  That's true in Java, Eiffel, C++, and every language that I know that uses them.

Personally I prefer runtime exceptions to enforce the contract.  You can't turn those off.

Comment: Yes, I have changed my opinion , may be runtime exceptions are strict but the right way to enforce the contract.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use assertion for validation of input data for your API. Simply throw runtime exception, if your API is used incorrectly, for example `IllegalArgumentException`

Answer (score 0):

Assertions are only used for **testing**. For other usage you should use exceptions or if structores (the second solution is preferred as it's much faster than catching exception)

Answer (score -2):

Neither assertions, nor exceptions should be used for implementing business logic. For one simple reason: **handling exception is a very slow**. Imagine, that your code is invoked very often, then handling bad input, would take too long. Just accepte one contract: check variables before invocation and pass only clean parameter or check variables with if statement in the begining of the method.

**UPD**:

> Assertions should be used to check something that should never happen,
>   while an exception should be used to check something that might
>   happen.

[Using Assertions in Java](http://java.sys-con.com/node/36819)

> Assertions throw an error instead of an exception because their
>   purpose is to crash your program.

[Class Error](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html)

> An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems
>   that a reasonable application should not try to catch. Most such
>   errors are abnormal conditions.

AssertionError is subclass of Error

Comment: The checks must do external modules not me and what if they not want to check? :)