# Catch exception, re-throw assertion

Tags: java

Consider following example. Is it considered a bad practise?

Note: I know re-throwing exception is ok, but what about assertionerror?

```
public static main(){
    try {
        doSmth();
    } catch (WhateverException we) {
        throw new AssertionError(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void doSmth() throws WhateverException { }
```

Comment: 1) It doesn't compile. 2) It swallows the stacktrace. 3) it can throw an NPE at exception creation (if it were changed to compile). 4) you should only ever throw classes that inherit from `Exception`, `AssertionError` is an `Error` not an `Exception`. In short, almost everything about this code is bad practice.

Comment: Well `AssertionError` is quite specific. If you're not doing comparisons and checks i would not recommend to throw an `AE`. Also throwing errors is mostly bad practise, unless you really want to kill your program

Comment: Why would you want to do that anyways? ...Assert is meant for Unit Testing

Comment: I don't think there is a point in throwing an Exception from inside another Exception. Throwing an Error is even worse.

Comment: @Rcordoval whilst it is true that assertions are _used_ in unit tests, an `AssertionError` is thrown by the Java [`assert` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907487/correct-use-java-assert-keyword) and this features in production code.

Comment: @DiegoVictordeJesus Exception chaining is very common and definitely has a point. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020876/what-is-the-advantage-of-chained-exceptions.

Comment: @DiegoVictordeJesus sorry, but you think wrong. The whole purpose of exceptions is to bubble up the stack. The user clicks a save button, that action goes all the way to the IO subsystem and that throws an `IOException` - as this exception travels up the stack each frame can add more context by wrapping and rethrowing (which file? what was the format? where in the UI?) etc - the final exception the UI gets will then have enough information to produce a meaningful error to the user - which just propogating an `IOException` would not.

Comment: Now I can see the point. Does this applies to runtime exceptions as well?

Comment: @DiegoVictordeJesus this applies to all exceptions - there is an open debate as to whether non-runtime exceptions should ever be used at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not bad practice to throw an error in response to an exception, if the exception indicates a situation that is fatal for your code. However:

- There's no need to use `AssertionError` in particular. I mean, it's fine if you do, since nobody's going to be `catch`ing one, but you should consider just doing `Error` instead, so that somebody doesn't go looking for the `assert` statement that they assumed caused it.
- When chaining a throwable like that, *always* use the old exception to construct the new one: `throw new AssertionError(we)`. That'll keep the old stack trace around. You can (and should) also pass a custom message.

Comment: Not sure I agree - I would state that throwing an `Error` is always wrong; the JVM is allowed to throw errors, you are not. Thowing a well named `RuntimeException` is the correct approach.