# java8: @NotNull vs Assertion vs Throwing Exception

Tags: java, validation, assertion, notnull

What's better to prevent the developer that my private method requires a notNull argument (Note that I am not using Spring framework)?

1. Use the @NotNull annotation

   ```
   private void myBusinessMethod(@NotNull Object argument){
       //...
   }
   ```

   Which library I have to choose ? `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull` ?
2. Use the assertion

   ```
   private void myBusinessMethod(Object argument){
       assert argument != null ;
       //...
   }
   ```
3. throw an IllegalArgumentException

   ```
   private void myBusinessMethod(Object argument){
       if (argument == null){
           throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Argument can't be null") ? 
       }
       //...
   }
   ```

In the following link is recommended to use the assertions: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=5

What do you think ?

Thank you

Comment: Matter of opinion. But I would go with the `IllegalArgumentException` **and** documentation pointing out that the parameter is expected to not be null.

Comment: There are other options like Lombok. I personally prefer checking arguments and throwing exceptions, for instance with `Objects.requireNotNull(argument, "Argument must not be null.")`.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963300/which-notnull-java-annotation-should-i-use

Comment: terrible question for points to be honest, a quick google search and you can find your answer. Would never up vote this in a million years..

Comment: @lexicore Objects.requireNotNull(argument, "Argument must not be null.") is similar to 3 option. it will throw NullPointerException in the running environment. I don't prefer this because it add an unnecessary check  to my code. Normally all the checks done once in the non private methods.

Comment: @CowboyFarnz "a quick google search and you can find your answer" - why don't you educate us then if it's so easy? The question is not trivial at all.

Comment: @lexicore [when to use an assertion vs exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957645/when-to-use-an-assertion-and-when-to-use-an-exception), there you go, viewed over 38,000 times and using annotation as NOTED, is a matter of preference.

Comment: @CowboyFarnz for sure I googled before posting my question, but I didn't find an affirmative response. 
The best thing I found is that : Objects.requireNotNull(argument, "Argument must not be null.") 

But I stay preferring use NotNull annotation because it is dedicated for validation simple and elegant .

Comment: @Aguid Correct, it is like the 3rd option. A pretty valid way to protect your code from being called with wrong parameters. Isn't it your objective?

Comment: @CowboyFarnz Thank you. This should have been your comment from the very start.

Comment: @lexicore Exactly. My goal is to prevent the user to quickly know which valid argument can use in his call of the private method.

Answer (score 2):

`@NotNull` is just an annotation and does nothing by itself. You can make use of Hibernate Validator library that provides and implementation of annotation processor to enforce the meaning of `@NotNull`. But more often than not, it suffices to have this annotation (for documentation) in combination with `thorws IllegalArgumentException`.
In addition, the resource pointed out by @lexicore (in the comments) should help.